# using app resource on background service without opening app

Tags: android, android-service

Salam
sorry for Weaknesses in language
i have a service running in back, when my service get destroyed because of low memory, i'm setting some code to recreate the service and initialize application class's parameter
my problem is when the service recreate and start to initialize, my app getting start too.
is there a way to prevent starting my app on recreate service ?

Comment: your Application or your Activity?

Comment: ok is there a way to prevent start main Activity ?

Comment: if it was not started it will not be started automatically

Comment: in my code just using ContentResolver and application class, no code for startActivity, but when service recreate, my app get start from main activity

Comment: i have no crystal ball and cannot read your minds or the code you didn't post

Comment: sorry I did not write the code, i was thinking if someone already had the same experience, maybe he could help

Comment: you don't write the code? what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was i call a AsyncTask class from my service, even if nothing doing in that.
i don't know why but changing AsyncTask class to simple class solved my problem.